# Php code to receive a StringBody from android?

Tags: php, android

```
entity.addPart("uploadedImage", new ByteArrayBody(data,"Image.jpg"));
```

To use the above image file I sent from android to php I use `$_FILES['uploadedImage']['name'];`

Can Anyone show me an example of how to do the same with a StringBody sent from android -

```
entity.addPart("ImageTitle", new StringBody(caption.getText().toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you can find it in `var_dump( $_REQUEST);` or `var_dump( $_POST);`.

My guess is that `$_REQUEST['ImageTitle']` or `$_POST['ImageTitle']` would work to retrieve the value from the request.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['ImageTitle'];` worked for me.